# How to compress and send sorted files in Python on Linux machine?

Tags: python, linux, file, email

I have a Python script that runs on our server. It produces some sorted .csv files and .PDF files with graphs. I am trying to build another script that will pick certain files and emails them to a group of users. Here is some kind of pseudo code:

- Process .CSV files: VC506.csv, VC507.csv, VC1020. csv and so on... based on certain criteria and produce an output file with the the
  list of all CSV files for which the criteria has been met. I did
  that part. So, I do have an output file. Let it be just a text file
  `output.txt`, or to make it better `todays_date_output.txt`
- The part i need to implement now is to Email that file with corresponding .pdf files. The name of PDF files are the same as .CSV files. To not confuse you, basically, if my
  script picked VC506.csv, VC507.csv files, then I will need to email
  VC506.pdf, VC507.pdf files.

  I guess the best idea is to put the output file and all those
  corresponding pdf files into one ZIP archive, since there could be lots of PDFs.

Email could look something like this:

```
Subject: testing results, July 10, 2013
Body: attached is the list of all the battery cells that appeared to be faulty.
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a question as a general plea for help, but you seem to be on the right track, since you have a clear outline of the solution. Now you just have to do it. Take a look at the documentation for [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) (for the file extensions), [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) and [email/smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) modules and you will be on your way.

Comment: I got emailing part working with just text so far. File messaging is not working yet, but I researched the web and it looks double. The biggest part for me is actually how to get the file  I needed for emailing. Yes, downvoting is easy, helping is harder. But I guess every noob has to face it.

Comment: You weren't downvoted for being a newbie, but rather because you didn't ask a specific and clear question. _Now_ you have a specific question, but it's not clear to me. If your problem is going from x.csv to x.pdf, take a look at the os.path.splitext function in the first link of my previous comment. That gets you the 'x', then you just need to add '.pdf'.

Comment: Well, thanks for the info.  I got sorting part working, I got messaging the files part working. But, I got stuck at (I guess) the easiest spot. I read through os.path module but is stills struggling with how to implement it. It is always hard when you do something for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got everything working. Was able to figure it out by myself with a little help of hints, provided by Paulo Almeida.

```
To get the filename with no extension i used:
```

> import os, os.path, zipfile, csv

```
path="processed_data/"  # insert the path to the directory of interest

dirList=os.listdir(path)
for filename in dirList:
    if filename.endswith((".csv")):
        file=os.path.splitext(filename)  #to stip off the extension
        statfiles.append(file[0])        # that will create a list with just the
                                         # filenames without extensions
```

Then to pick the needed files and pack them to zip:

```
pdfs = zipfile.ZipFile("pdfs.zip","w")
for item in statfiles:
   pdfs.write('pdf_folder/'+item+'.pdf')
pdfs.close()
```

To send via email I just used a script, found here on StackOVerflow. 
If this post ever helps anybody, I ll get another point to my karma ))
Good luck.